# Generate wrapper procedure (with parameter) to call procedure from rolling Databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have three databases.

- Master
- Slave1
- Slave2

A Procedure runs on the master, which fetches data from one of the slaves. If this is done, the second one is connected.

I always want to call the procedure 'Fetch' from the master. On the master I call the warpper procedure like this

`exec slave1.dbo.fetch.`

The wrapper looks like this

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo. [fetch]
AS
BEGIN
exec slave1.dbo.[fetch]
END
```

To convert this as a dynamic call (exchange slave1 by slave2) is still relatively simple.

It gets more complicated when I have more than one procedure and they have parameters. Then I always have to keep the number of parameters and the types of parameters in sync.

How can I do that for a lot of procedures dynamically?

Comment: for sync data between 3 data base you use SSIS and **data tools** - you can create a package for syn data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-how-to-create-an-etl-package?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yes, I've been using SSIS for several years. Just to synchronize the data this would be an option. But the procedure also does the processing (maybe the procedurename Fetch was not the best choice)